# How does this power supply make PWM?

Tags: power-supply, pwm

I am beginner in power supply repair.

Can anyone completely explain to me how this power supply make PWM without a PWM IC in the primary side?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You say "no IC" yet in the 2nd photo I see a TO92 case with the text "ic2" printed next to it. I am not saying that this is the PWM controller. Show us the full schematic and we might haev a better idea how this supply works.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie there isn't any available schematic

Comment: Voting to close. This is a variant of your existing question on the same board, with the same photos and with no effort shown again: 
 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562349/how-can-i-make-schematic-of-this-board

Comment: I posted an X-Ray view in your previous question. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562349/how-can-i-make-schematic-of-this-board

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand how it works, then sketch out the schematic. I’ve been doing this for years. It’s a useful skill. After some practice you can identify what type of power supply topology it is.

My guess for yours is a ‘ringing choke’ converter. Google the Apple II power supply circuit - i’d expect it will be similar.

IC2 will probably be a TL431 shunt regulator. The low voltage side is usually quite simple.

Sone hints for repairing these supplies - high value resistors frequently fail, so I’d be checking those 680k ones. Electrolytic caps wear out. Get yourself an ESR meter. Next to a multimeter probably the most handiest bit of test equipment.

[edit] two minutes of Googling. [Transistor replacement for power supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/269492/transistor-replacement-for-power-supply)

How does it work?

D5,R5 and C4 are the feedback circuit that makes it oscillate along with the feedback winding on the transformer which also supplies alow voltage to the optocoupler.

Q2,R2,R3 and C3 are the current limit circuit.

R4 supplies the startup voltage to kick off the oscillation. This resistor commonly fails due to overvoltage.

Comment: It works very well right now, but i cant understand how it work ! 
thank you for useful information.